# Add item purchases to android app from African country

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

I am a programmer in Africa and I am working on an android app for some shopping mall. My question is how do I implement item purchases from VISA card since the google merchant account is not available to my country and not even STRIPE... etc. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: You need to choose account from different country where merchant account is available.

Comment: Don't they need me to be from that country? The details while signing up??

Comment: Yes you need to create account with details having different country.

Comment: Thanks will try that